# Fullcalendar - Year view, month title disable link

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm currently trying to make a Year calendar only.

I've disabled the navigation between days and months and removed the header (with the buttons).

BUT, on the year display, months are links. When you click on it, that changes the type of the calendar display (year display => month display).

In my case, because I disabled the header, if someone clicks on that month link they can't go back to the year view...so the calendar becomes unusable.

Does someone know how to disable that "month link"?

```
$('#calendarRoomUnavailable').fullCalendar({
        height: 'auto',
        header: {
            left : '',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        defaultView: 'year',
        defaultDate: currentDayStart,
        lang: 'fr',
        firstDay: 1,
        columnFormat: 'ddd D/M',
        weekends: false,
        navLinks : false,
        events: basePath + '/agenda/datalist/room_available',
        viewRender: function (view, element) {
            $(element).find('tbody td').css('cursor', 'pointer');
            currentDayStart = view['start'];
            currentViewType = view['type'];
        },
        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

[...]

        },
        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

            [...]

        },
    });
```

Code behind the month link.

```
<div class="fc-year-monthly-name fc-first">
<a name="201801" data-year="2018" data-month="0" href="#">Janvier</a>
</div>
```

Thanks

[Exemple with the 'month link'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X1Kp.jpg)

Comment: You haven't shown your code, but please check your settings in relation to the things documented here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-nav-links

Comment: @ADyson I don't think code is needed in that case, but tell me which code do you want?
(I've linked a screenshot in the post, more relevant than code, no?)

Comment: No, because we can't fix pictures. It's fine to provide a screenshot, because it's nice to help to visualise the problem, but we have no idea how you made it get like that, so we have no idea how to advise you to change it.

Comment: @ADyson I've updated my post for the init code of the calendar.

Comment: Ok thanks. So, `defaultView: 'year'`...there's no built-in "year" view in fullCalendar. Is this some custom view you've defined? Is it a completely custom view or just some settings (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-views)? I don't know how it builds those month names and the links that appear to be attached to them. You've got `navLinks:false` so we can assume it's not that functionality which is causing it.

Comment: @ADyson POST edited for the code, thx for your replies. `defaultView: 'year'` is not a custom view, I just use a normal mode defined by fullcalendar.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/defaultView
_A name of any of the available views._

Comment: Sorry but you're wrong. "year" is not one of the "available views" by default. This fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qxLuLhsf/162/ is using the latest fullcalendar (3.9.0) and there is no "year" view available, hence the blank calendar, and the console error saying _"Uncaught Error: View type "year" is not valid"_. You must be using some kind of custom version. As you can see from looking at https://fullcalendar.io/docs#main, the standard view types are "month", "agenda", "list" and "basic" (and "timeline" if you buy the Scheduler add-on). Then there are the custom view options. That's all.

Comment: As such, until you show us the code for this custom view we have no idea how the links are being created, or what code is triggered when you click on them, or how you might go about suppressing that behaviour.

Comment: @ADyson Oh ok, I'm not alone to work on that project. This view is use many times, so I'll not destroy the template just for my case.
Thanks for your help again !